# I don't know where to start to prove this

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Determine by using Euclid’s theorem that
If $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k \in N^*$ are relatively
prime pairwise then
$N_i = n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n_k/n_i$ and $n_i$ are relatively prime for $i \leq 1 \leq k$.

Is $ n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n_k$ divided by $n_i$ or just $n_k$ is being divided by $n_i$?

What does prime two by two really mean?

Can someone give me a hint on what to do to prove that?

Comment: I think $n_1, n_2,...,n_k$ are relatively prime two by two means that for all distinct $i,j\in\{1,2,...,k\},$ we have $\gcd(n_i,n_j)=1.$

Comment: is $n_j = n_i + 1$ ?

Comment: For example, $6, 10, 17$ are not relatively prime two by two because $6$ and $10$ are not relatively prime

Comment: "Two by two" here probably just means "pairwise" (relatively prime, in this case).

Comment: "Is n1⋅n2⋅…⋅nk divided by ni or just nk is being divided by ni?"  Doesn't matter.  $a\frac bc = \frac {ab}c = \frac acb = ab\frac 1c$.  .... However in this case they mean  $\frac {n_1*n_2*...*n_{i-1}*n_i*n_{i+1}*...*n_k}{n_i} = n_1*n_2*.....*n_{i-1}*n_{i+j1}*....*n_k$.  In other words "everthing multiplied together *except* one of the $n_i$".

Answer (score 1):

> What does prime two by two really mean?

Two numbers are relatively prime if they have no non-trivial factors in common.

But consider *three* numbers $6,10,15$.  In *pairs* no two of them are relatively prime $6,10$ have a $2$ in common.  $10,15$ have a $3$ in common and $6,15$ have a $3$ in common.

But as a group, $6,10,15$ have no factor (other than $1$) in common.  So as a *group* $6,10,15$ are relatively prime.  But pairwise (I've never seen a book say "two by two") they are not.

> What does  $n_1*n_2*.....*n_k/n_i$ mean?

Th text is trying to express the idea of

$\overline n_i = (n_1*n_2*.......*n_{i-1})*(n_{i+1}*....*n_k)$

That is $\overline n_i=$ the product of all the terms *except* $n_i$.

And they use the idea that

$\overline n_i*\frac {n_i}{n_i} =\frac {n_1*......*n_k}{n_i}$ and .... that's an easier way to express it.

> So what is the problem saying.

If $n_1, ....,n_k$ are a group of numbers that pairwise are relatively prime.... we could formally express that as where $n_i$ and $n_j$ are relatively prime whenever $i\ne j$..... then prove that the group $\overline{n_i}$ are relatively prime as a group.  (They most certainly will *not* be pairwise relatively prime, BTW).

Example.

If we are given $2,3,5$ which are pairwise relatively prime, prove that the numbers:

$\frac {2*3*5}2 = 3*5=15$

$\frac {2*3*5}3 = 2*5 =10$

$\frac {2*3*5}5= 2*3 = 6$

are relatively prime as a group.

Or say that numbers are $22, 21, 25, 13$ are pairwise relatively prime then

$\frac {22*21*25*13}{22} = 21*25*13 = 6825,$

$\frac {22*21*25*13}{21}= 22*25*13 = 7150,$

$\frac {22*21*25*13}{25} = 21*22*13 = 6006,$

And $\frac {22*21*25*13}{13} = 21*22*25 = 11550$

are as a group relatively prime.

Can you prove that in general:

Hint:  If $f|n_i$ does $f|n_j$?  Does $f|\overline{n_i}$?  Does $f|\overline{n_j}$?

Comment: It just asks if each $\bar{n}_i$ is relatively prime to $n_i$, which is easier than showing that the set of all the $\bar{n}_i$ has no common factors, imo.

Comment: Hmm.... you are right.  That *is* what the question is asking.  Which is so trivial and obvious that it didn't even occur to me that anyone would consider asking it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be
$N_i = (n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n_k)/n_i.$
Let p be a prime that divides $N_i$ and $n_i$.
Then exist j /= i with p divides $n_j$.
As the n's are pairwise relatively prime, ...

Answer (score 0):

Two numbers are relatively prime iff they have no common factors other than one. A set of integers are pairwise relatively prime if for any two of them, the pair is relatively prime.

If two numbers share a common factor other than one, this factor is prime or divisible by a prime by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. A common factor greater than one implies at least one prime common factor.

If we take the product of a group of pair-wise relatively prime numbers, X, and divide by one of them, a, we have removed from the product all primes contributed to N by a. N/a therefor has no primes in common with a. So N/a and a are relatively prime.